# Naive Bayes classfier prove

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics

I have a question about the binary classifier about the way to prove it as a linear classifier.
For example, Consider binary classification where the class attribute $y$ takes two values: $0$ or $1$. Let
the feature vector for a test instance be a $d$-dimensional vector $x$. A linear classier with the model parameter $w$ is the following function:

$$
y=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }w^\ast x>0, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

We have assumption that $x$ is a binary vector and only have value of $1$ or $0$ in each dimension.

How to prove this Naive bayes classier is a linear classifier in $(d + 1)$-dimensional space?

My thoughts:

I found some materials to prove some similar classfiers to be linear with the the calculation of the decision boundary then calculate the $w$ using log-probabilities. 
However, I could not find anything with dimensions in place with the proof, any help will be appreciated.